# Can OpenFileDialog automatically select the file with the value set in FileName if InitialDirectory is set as well?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

This is nit picky but why doesn't the file get automatically selected if it exists and both `FileName` and `InitialDirectory` are set correctly?

I have an `OpenFileDialog` with both `FileName` and `InitialDirectory` set correctly and the files exists in this folder.  Why isn't the file selected when I run the `ShowDialog()` method?

No file is selected but it would be nice if it was selected so I wouldn't have to scroll down to select the next file adjacent to it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is weird, can you post the code that creates and initializes your dialog?

Comment: I think the only way to do that is through pinvoking your way to get the ListView box and selecting it yourself.  The last answer to this thread [OpenFileDialog - how to select files by coding???](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/262498-openfiledialog-how-select-files-coding) *might* be helpful.

Comment: So 'nit picky' that I've opened a bounty for it. On the contrary this could be a massive time saver for some niche operations.

Comment: This question also asks the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520611/c-sharp-programatically-highlight-file-in-openfiledialog

Answer (score 13):

Maybe it is not perfect but it meets the expectation somehow.

I have a `Button` that Shows `OpenFileDialog` on click event. And async method that will SendKeys to OpenFileDialog.

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
                string initialDir = "directory\\";
                string FileName = "filename.smthng";
                string combinedDir = initialDir + FileName;
                if (File.Exists(combinedDir)) // if there is a file with that name at that directory
                {
                    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = initialDir; // setting directory name
                    openFileDialog1.FileName = FileName; // filename
                    BeginInvoke((Action)(() => openFileDialog1.ShowDialog())); // we need to use BeginInvoke to continue to the following code.
                    await SendKey(FileName); // Sends Key to Dialog 
                }
                else // if there is not file with that name works here because no keys need to send.
                {
                    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = initialDir;
                    openFileDialog1.FileName = FileName;
                    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                }
    
    }

    private async Task SendKey(string FileName){
            await Task.Delay(250); // Wait for the Dialog shown at the screen
            SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}"); // First Shift + Tab moves to Header of DataGridView of OpenFileDialog
            SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}"); // Second Shift + Tab moves to first item of list
            SendKeys.SendWait(FileName); // after sending filename will directly moves it to the file that we are looking for
    }
```

**Result;**

[image: openfiledialog]

### Edit 1;

Okay, For `.Net 3.5` there is also `TaskParalelLibrary` but using Thread will be much easier.

```
 Thread t;
 private const string initialDir = "C:\\";
 private const string FileName = "test.txt";
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
       string combinedDir = initialDir + FileName;
       if (File.Exists(combinedDir)) // if there is a file with that name at that directory
            {
                openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = initialDir; // setting directory name
                openFileDialog1.FileName = FileName; // filename
                BeginInvoke((Action)(() => openFileDialog1.ShowDialog())); // we need to use BeginInvoke to continue to the following code.
                t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendKey)); // Sends Key to Dialog with an seperate Thread.
                t.Start(); // Thread starts.
            }
            else // if there is not file with that name works here because no keys need to send.
            {
                openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = initialDir;
                openFileDialog1.FileName = FileName;
                openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
      
        private void SendKey()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // Wait for the Dialog shown at the screen
            SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}"); // First Shift + Tab moves to Header of DataGridView of OpenFileDialog
            SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}"); // Second Shift + Tab moves to first item of list
            SendKeys.SendWait(FileName); // after sending filename will directly moves it to the file that we are looking for
        }
```

Comment: Looks promising. I'm using .NET 3.5. The keywords 'async', 'SendKey' and 'await' are red squiggly. How can I solve that?

Comment: Doesn't appear to work unfortunately. It navigates to the correct folder, and also the filename is in the FileName text box (highlighted), but unfortunately, the file is not highlighted or focused within the file list view.

Comment: @DanW Did you try increase thread's sleep time? Maybe your dialog appears much faster then I. If you tried already, debug please and say, this part is not working. Otherwise it is difficult to say..

Comment: Still no joy even after `Thread.Sleep(1000);`. The requester appears almost instantly btw.

Comment: @DanW did sendwait works? Are you sure that the file exist? Else block may be executed only. I provide a working code and a gif.

Comment: Okay, it works now (I think I stupidly had the test.txt in a folder level above). Which answer do you think deserves the bounty? I mean I suppose the other answer negates the need for the Sleep function...

Comment: @DanW It is up to you, ı can't decide it :)

Answer (score 10):

## SendKeys

SendKeys seems like a hack but it is the easiest and for the reasons explained below probably more sustainable long term than using Win32 APIs.

Relying on a `await Task.Delay(250);` **is risky**. The timeout might be too quick before a dialog shows on a slow system,  on the other hand if the timeout is increased a fast user might interact while competing with the SendKeys automation.

I recommend you **use the Message Loop to notify when to SendKeys**.

```
bool IsOpenFileDialog = false;
private void openDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsOpenFileDialog = true;
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    IsOpenFileDialog = false;
}

uint _lastDialogHandle = 0;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (!IsOpenFileDialog) return;
    if (m.Msg == 289) //Notify of message loop
    {
        try
        {
            uint dialogHandle = (uint)m.LParam; //handle of the file dialog
            if (dialogHandle != _lastDialogHandle) //only when not already changed
            {
                _lastDialogHandle = dialogHandle;
                SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}");   
                SendKeys.SendWait(EscapeSendKeySpecialCharacters("temp.xls"));

                //Or try via Win32
                //List<string> childWindows = GetDialogChildWindows(dialogHandle);
                //TODO set ListView Item
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}

private string EscapeSendKeySpecialCharacters(string sentence)
{
    sentence = sentence.Replace("+", "{+}");
    sentence = sentence.Replace("^", "{^}");
    sentence = sentence.Replace("%", "{%}");
    sentence = sentence.Replace("~", "{~}");
    sentence = sentence.Replace("(", "{(}");
    sentence = sentence.Replace(")", "{)}");
    return sentence;
}
```

> Note: The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}).

**So for example if your filename has parentheses you need to escape them with curly brackets:**

```
SendKeys.SendWait("New Text Document - Copy {(}8{)}.txt");
```

---

## Win32 (attempt - incomplete and not working)

You could try iterating through the OpenFileDialogs' Child Windows to find the listview control:

```
private List<string> GetDialogChildWindows(dialogHandle) {
//IEnumerable<IntPtr> allWindows = EnumWindowsAndChild.EnumAllWindows((IntPtr)dialogHandle, "Dialog");
List<IntPtr>  children = EnumWindowsAndChild.GetChildWindows((IntPtr)dialogHandle);
List<string> childWindows = new List<string>();
foreach (IntPtr ptr in children)
{
    string s = ptr.ToString() + ",  " + EnumWindowsAndChild.GetWindowsTextTitle(ptr) + ", " + EnumWindowsAndChild.GetWindowClassName(ptr);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        childWindows.Add(s);
   }
  return childWindows;
 }
```

The Enum Windows and Child class helper:

```
public static class EnumWindowsAndChild
{
    public delegate bool Win32Callback(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr parentHandle, Win32Callback callback, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static public extern IntPtr GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

    private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
    {
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
        List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
        if (list == null)
            throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
        list.Add(handle);
        return true;
    }

    public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
    {
        List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
        GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
        try
        {
            Win32Callback childProc = new Win32Callback(EnumWindow);
            EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                listHandle.Free();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static string GetWinClass(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            return null;
        StringBuilder classname = new StringBuilder(100);
        IntPtr result = GetClassName(hwnd, classname, classname.Capacity);
        if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
            return classname.ToString();
        return null;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> EnumAllWindows(IntPtr hwnd, string childClassName)
    {
        List<IntPtr> children = GetChildWindows(hwnd);
        if (children == null)
            yield break;
        foreach (IntPtr child in children)
        {
            if (GetWinClass(child) == childClassName)
                yield return child;
            foreach (var childchild in EnumAllWindows(child, childClassName))
                yield return childchild;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetWindowTextLength(HandleRef hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(HandleRef hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    public static string GetWindowsTextTitle(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        int capacity = GetWindowTextLength(new HandleRef(null, hwnd)) * 2;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(capacity);
        GetWindowText(new HandleRef(null, hwnd), stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity);
        return stringBuilder.ToString();

    }

    public static string GetWindowClassName(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(128);
        GetClassName(hWnd, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
        return buffer.ToString();
    }
}
```

Once you have the Hwnd to the ListView you could try to set its item, but you'd need to use a NativeWindow and its not going to be pretty, see this article to know what I mean: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2890/Using-ListView-control-under-Win-API

As much as I hate to admit it, this is one of the rare cases where I'd suggest SendKeys over the Win32 API. Win32 Api's might not even work in the end and SendKeys is much more likely to continue to work if/when the APIs change. For example we saw with XP to Vista, the API `FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle)` is now almost useless since Aero hides the Windows Captions which are needed for the windowTitle parameter. One solution is to use Classic Theme, not many people will accept that, so this is one of the reasons I wouldn't count on Win32 apis to do **this particular** thing and simply use SendKeys instead. See here:

[image]

I couldn't get any of this stuff to work anymore: https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/262498-openfiledialog-how-select-files-coding, which is from a Microsoft email Dist.

```
// Getting the handle of the ListBox in the OpenFileDialog dialog.
uint listviewHandle = FindWindowEx(dialogHandle, 0,
"SHELLDLL_DefView", "");

// Sending message to the ListBox to set the view to Thumbnails
//Icons=0x7029, List=0x702b, Details=0x702c, Thumbnails=0x702d,
Tiles=0x702e
SendMessage(listviewHandle, 0x0111/*WM_COMMAND*/, (uint)0x702d, 0);

// Sending message to the ListBox to select all items.
SendMessage(listviewHandle, 0x0111/*WM_COMMAND*/, (uint)0x00017021,
(uint)0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first chunk of code appears to be missing close brackets. And I'm wondering whether the section of code below that is supposed to be part of that chunk or separated (and put with my own code). Could you update the answer please?

Comment: Ok that should make it a little clearer, the formatting is not 100% as edited on my phone. The Win32 code is a start if you want to go down that route. The method of SendKeys as soon as the Dialog shows is working and complete, cheers

Comment: Had to add "catch {}" after the try section, "uint" before dialogHandle in the GetDialogChildWindows method, and also add "uint _lastDialogHandle;" as a class variable, so you might want to edit those in.

Comment: Have you tried this and does it work successfully for you? The only code I have got outside your own is a button event with the line `DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();`. Here's what happens for me. I open the dialog, and although the file section is in focus (allowing me to scroll up and down with the cursor keys), the "New Text Document - Copy (8).txt" file is not selected. See: http://i.imgur.com/Hzsr2mK.png

Comment: Hi, it does work for me as per temp.xls being selected in the screenshot. Notice in my code how I SendKeys a filename (temp.xls) in your screenshot in looks like you used the full file path.

Comment: Okay, getting there although I'm getting some weird behaviour now. It looks like the problem occurs with parenthesis. To reproduce my problem, create a new Text Document (via Windows), and copy it numerous times. And then try and select the file (say) "New Text Document - Copy (4).txt". It'll select one of the others instead. There'll be a 'ding' sound as well.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that certain characters need to be escaped for SendKeys, please see latest edit. Cheers

Comment: Okay, Method 1 (SendKeys) appears to work great! However I could not get Method 2 (Win32) to work. There are hints in your answer that the "Win32" section is indeed incomplete, so if this is the case, you may want to add "incomplete" or "not yet working" next to your "Win32" title.

Comment: Yeah I should have made that clear, many of the other answers mention the Win32 way and I explored it a bit and gave it ago but I don't think it will even work without native. Tempted to remove the Win32 stuff altogether.

Comment: Congrats on the bounty! Works a treat.