# C# programmatically highlight file in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

In C#, once an OpenFileDialog is opened in a specific directory, I would like to be able to set which file in the list is selected (highlighted) as though it had been single-clicked.  This will help users remember where they "left off" if they happen to use this dialog multiple times in a row to select sequential files.

Does C# offer a way to do this?  Do I need to use a lower-level construct?

Comment: You surely have to use low-level programming here :) not easy.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347585/can-openfiledialog-automatically-select-the-file-with-the-value-set-in-filename/39781860#39781860)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply set the `FileName` property.

Comment: THanks for the quick reply.  For me, setting the FileName property has the effect of populating the FileName text box with my value, but not highlighting that row in the list...unless perhaps the file name needs to be in some special format in order for it to be recognized correctly...?