# How to add Hotkeys to CommonOpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, windows-api-code-pack

I am using Microsoft's CommonOpenFileDialog to allow users to select a Folder.
How i can add Hotkeys commands to click on select folder button in dialog.

[image]

Comment: Take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347585/can-openfiledialog-automatically-select-the-file-with-the-value-set-in-filename/39781860#39781860)

Comment: I need add hotkey for Select Folder button in  the dialog