# Is there a way to set filenames from OpenFileDialog through code?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to set filenames from OpenFileDialog through code?

```
    string[] files = {"D:\\test1.txt","D:\\test2.txt"};
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Multiselect = true;
    dialog.FileNames = files;
```

Error while trying to set the FileNames:
Error   CS0200  Property or indexer 'FileDialog.FileNames' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Why did you want to "set filenames"?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish. What good is it to set the file name in an open file dialog?

Comment: The OpenFileDialog class is only used to select one or more files and is read-only and cannot be set

Comment: The question sounds legitimate to me. Sometimes, applications requires to read a file with a very specific filename (first example that comes to my mind are related to some build tools : `web.config` for ASP.Net, `tsconfig.json` for typescript compiler options, .... Or sometimes file names must match kind of business name.  That said, isn't the [filter format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_Filter) able to specify filenames instead of wildcard + extention ?

Comment: Perhaps: `d.FileName = string.Join(" ", files.Select(f => string.Format(@"""{0}""", f)));`. Just to fill the name box. It won't select any.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use `InitialDirectory` to set the default address

```
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "D:\\";
```

and use `openFileDialog.Filter` to set specific type

```
openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
```

and you can use `openFileDialog1.FileName` to select a file

```
openFileDialog1.FileName = "test1"
```

or muliplefile

```
openFileDialog1.FileName = "\"test1\" \"test2\"";
```

For example:

```
string message = "";
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\\";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
openFileDialog1.FileName = "\"test1\"\"test2\""; 
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {
        message += Path.GetFileName(file) + " - " + file + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Comment: I checked that quoted filename for multiple selection works, but is there a way to have them selected in the file panel and not only mentionned in the bottom textbox?

Comment: for this question visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347585/can-openfiledialog-automatically-select-the-file-with-the-value-set-in-filename

Comment: Yes ... but this link is a bit complex, and requires low level code. Does this work with the hack exposed in your answer to preselect several filenames?

Comment: ```OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog(); openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\\"; openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (.txt)|.txt"; openFileDialog1.FileName = "\"test1\" \"test2\""; MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileNames.Count);``` Assigned two files using the above code and the total count of files shows as 1 instead of two. Why the count is not two?

Comment: @Chaya It works for me, but the files need to exist, so here perhaps test1 and test2 does not exist... You need to test with real filenames (without paths) that must be in the initial directory. Also, the selected processed FileNames extracted list is only available after the ShowDialog resulting in OK. Before, Filenames is a single item string from Filename... thus 1.