# Pre-select a file when using TOpenPictureDialog

Tags: delphi

I want to use TOpenPictureDialog.Execute to open file explorer with the previously selected file selected. At the moment it opens automatically in the last used folder but with no file selected so always at the beginning of the file list.  There are many files in the folder and is nearly always the case that the user wants to select the next one or close to the next one after processing the previous one so it would improve efficiency if the dialog would auto scroll to the position of the last opened file.

Comment: Are you setting the `FileName` property to the last selected file *before* calling `Execute`?

Comment: No straightforward way. Some send keys to the dialog as seen in an answer for the same question in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347585/can-openfiledialog-automatically-select-the-file-with-the-value-set-in-filename

Comment: Thanks.  Seems odd that it works this way but I will see if I can use send keys to do what I want. re Remy the last used filename shows in file explorer and is in the dialog's FileName property if I inspect it in debug mode.